# Reverse a regular expression asp

Tags: asp.net, regex, vba, validation

HI I have a validator that take mobilephonenr

```
+467
07

ValidationExpression="^(07).+|(\+?467).+$">
```

I want to reverse the expression to another validator so you **cant** type in

```
+467 
07
```

Do I need to du a function or cant I just reverse it like in `C#` `!isNot`

Comment: what do you mean by saying "reverse the expression to another validator" ?

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead:

```
^(?!07|\+?467).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oB0zE3)**

Comment: as a side note, the `.*` will validate empty input. `.+` might be better suited to OP's need

Comment: @Ploutox Yes, but in OP's context it doesn't matter, since empty input in asp.net won't be validated by regex anyway.

Comment: If i only want to match 10 or 12 digits inklunde the +
Like
0736585787
+46736585787